# Transposing Collection of Cells from an Open Workbook

Tags: vba, foreach, excel-2007

Here's the backstory:  I've been enjoying VBA's versatility in Excel 2007, but I'm getting stuck trying to reference a range of cells from another workbook.  More explicitly, I'd like to create a columnar list starting in cell I12 in ThisWorkbook using the For Each Next process, which will grab the cell values (of varying quantity) from the first row of the sheet (sheet variable is CompShtName) in the OldFile workbook.  Here is the excerpt of code I've written:

```
CompShtName = Range("E12").Value 
For Each Cell In OldFile.Sheets(CompShtName).Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlRight))  **<---Run-time error 1004**  
    Range("I" & 12 + i).Value = Cell.Value  
    i = i + 1  
Next
```

I've declared and defined the variables where: `OldFile = file` address for the old file, `CompShtName = name` of sheet in OldFile, and `i = counter`.  When I try to run the code, I get `run-time error 1004` in the line containing the arrow.

I thought maybe the problem lay in pulling from another book.  But if I change the range to something more simple, like `Range("A1:A5")`, it works.  I even tried removing  `OldFile.Sheets(CompShtName).` and letting it run using the active `ThisWorkbook`, but that works, too.  So the problem must be from try to create an unwieldy collection.

---

UPDATE

I really like @Zemens approach using transposition instead of a loop.  I also made sure to properly qualify my range, using the suggestion from @mehow.  Unfortunately, I'm still getting a 1004 error.  Here is the updated code exceprt:

`Dim OldSht As Worksheet`
`Dim EndOldHeader As Range`
`Set OldSht = OldFile.Sheets(CompShtName)`
`Set EndOldHeader = OldSht.Cells(1, OldSht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight))`  `Compare.Range("I12").Resize(EndOldHeader.Columns.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(EndOldHeader.Value)`

The error occurs in the `Set EndOldHeader` line.

Comment: try `For Each Cell In OldFile.Sheets(CompShtName).Cells(1, OldFile.Sheets(CompShtName).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight))`

Comment: You don't need a loop to tranpsose columns to rows like this. But you do need to qualify your range objects :)

Comment: Have you had a chance to try my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unqualified Range object `Range("A1").End(xlRight)` is assumed *always* to refer to the `ActiveWorkbook`.  You need to fully qualify it, per @mehow's comment.

The 1004 error raises because it is not possible to construct a Range object that spans multiple workbooks :)

I find it better when working with large constructs like this to create object variables to represent them. They are easier to read, update, maintain, and debug in the future.

However, you can do this without a loop structure. It should be faster, although might not be noticeably faster.

```
Dim oldSheet as Worksheet
Dim oldRange as Range
Dim cl as Range
Set oldSheet = OldFile.Sheets(CompShtName)
Set oldRange = oldSheet.Cells(1, oldSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight))

ActiveSheet.Range("I12").Resize(oldRange.Columns.Count,1).Value = Application.Transpose(oldRange.Value)
```

Or, to do in the loop like:

```
For each cl in oldRange.Cells
    ActiveSheet.Range("I" & 12 + i).Value = cl.Value  
    i = i + 1  
Next
```

Comment: and @mehow, your comments are very helpful! I've implemented your suggestions, but I'm still getting error 1004. Here's the code, with the error occuring at the `Set EndOldHeader` line: `Set OldSht = OldFile.Sheets(CompShtName)` `Set EndOldHeader = OldSht.Cells(1, OldSht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight))` `Compare.Range("I12").Resize(EndOldHeader.Columns.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(EndOldHeader.Value)`

Comment: Don't put code in comments, revise or add to your original question.

Comment: do you have any suggestion about the line that is still giving me trouble?  It's written in the updates section.  I've been trying to create a work-around, but so far nothing has worked.

Comment: Try `endOldHeader = Range(oldSht.Cells(1, 1), oldSht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight))` although this returns the entire `Row 1`, it shouldn't error.

Comment: It's almost there!  I'm no longer getting the error on that line, but I'm now getting a 438 error on the next line (`Compare.Range`).  From what I've read in Help and on forums, this error may not be a simple coding fix.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what is `Compare`?  You did not provide enough code for me to determine what this is/represents. That type of object/variable is it?

Comment: Resolve!  I had mistakenly read `ActiveSheet` in your very first response to mean I could write the variable name of my active workbook.  Once I made the change to read exactly how you had written it, along with making a couple other minor changes, the code ran smoothly.  Thank you again for all of your help in answering my questions!!

Comment: I noticed that actually after your last comment, and changed my answer from `ThisWorkbook...` to `ActiveSheet`. My mistake :)